# Flatten doubly nested lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

How to convert this:

```
[[[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']], [[4,5], ['d','e']], [[6,7,8,9], ['f','g','h','i']]]
```

to this:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']]
```

Knowing python, there must be some way using zip and list comprehensions.

Comment: Combine `zip` with [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406121), by the looks of it.

Comment: Closing this as a dupe, as there isn't anything novel enough here apart from looping over the `zip(*inputlist)` output first, then applying the other answer to every element from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a task for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [itertools.chain.from_iterable()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
data = [[[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']], [[4,5], ['d','e']], [[6,7,8,9], ['f','g','h','i']]]
list(zip(*data))
```

This will give you

```
[([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]), (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])]
```

Now apply `chain.from_iterable` for the inner lists:

```
data = [[[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']], [[4,5], ['d','e']], [[6,7,8,9], ['f','g','h','i']]]
print([list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(inner)) for inner in zip(*data)])
```

Comment: As I said, just combine `zip()` with the dupe.

Comment: I was writing my answer while the question was flagged as duplicate and I didn't want to throw it away. I'm going to check the dupe now.